# How to add to an Update statement

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am trying to update my database(Table) and make the active column = 1.
I have duplicate reports (subject_text) with different countries and parameters.

```
subject_text   countries   parameter1  active   
usage          GB         1           0
usage          FR         2           0
usage          PT         1           0
closed       GB,FR,PT     1           0
```

Here is an example of what my database looks like(simplified, there are many more parameters and many more reports but i hope you can see what I mean by duplicate report names)

Here is my .cs file to show the update i am trying to carry out.The Subject_text are in drop-down list form so the user can select which report to update. These reports(subject_text) are hard-coded into my ASPX page. When selecting a report such as 'closed' the update works, but when it comes to updating reports which have different countries or parameters that where i'm having trouble.

`Masterpage master`is linking this page to where the .getDropDownListValue is

How can I add to my update statement when the drop-down lists contain different elements?

```
protected void RunReport_Click (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{ 

 MasterPage master = (MasterPage)this.Master;
    string sqlStatement = "";

sqlStatement = @"UPDATE [TODD].[dbo].[Table] SET Active='1' WHERE subject_text = @report";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, conn);
cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, conn);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@report", ddl_Report.SelectedItem.Text);

string getcountry = master.getDropDownListValue(ddl_country, false);
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(getcountry))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", getcountry);
    sqlStatement += "AND countries = @country";
}
string getparam1 = master.getDropDownListValue(Param1, false);
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(getparam1))
    { 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", getparam1);
    sqlStatement += "AND parameter1 = @param1";
    }


conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What's the current problem? Are you getting errors? Not clear on what trouble you're having. Are you sure you're getting back what you expect from your getDropDownListValue method?

Comment: your table has a column "country", but your sql refers to "countries"

Comment: @joe thank you, that was a typo my mistake

Comment: @AndyWiesendanger no errors are occurring which makes me think its to do with the get drop down value, if i misspell AND for example and i update there is no error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

move

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, conn);
```

to below the final calculation of your string `sqlStatement`

adding new text to `sqlStatement` should be done before you create your `SqlCommand` based on `sqlStatement`

also, you do not need to call `new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, conn);` twice

Comment: when i move, `cmd.parameters` go red, cannot use before declared?

Comment: step 1 - do all of your logic to create the string sqlStatement.  step 2 - create your SqlCommand object based on that string.  Once that is done, any additional changes to the sqlStatement string are ignored.  step 3 - do all of your logic to add your parameters.

Comment: after thinking about this further...   if your table has a composite key of subject_text and countries, then you should always use both of those in your where clause, whether you need them or not.  Do not use logic to sometimes add them in, and sometimes omit them... your composite key should always be used in full.  This will eliminate your additional logic.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer guidance and time, it is very much appreciated. The thing is that i have other columns with null values or duplicate countries that are chosen by what are passed by other parameters. could I add in a recordId like Moe has suggested? or have another column with the number or the report so when the user selects the correct report it makes active=1 from the number it has been given?

Comment: You can add an additional ID column, if you want to. The important thing to know is, that each table should have a unique way of identifying each individual row.  In some cases, that is a composite key that would include subject_text, countries, parameter.  In other cases, it would be an integer ID behind the scenes that the user probably never sees.  Since this is software, there are literally an infinite number of ways to solve your problem.  You can easily perform the three steps that I mentioned in my earlier comment with a little cut-n-paste, or you can use Moe's excellent suggestion.

Comment: Another key point that i wanted to relay... once you create a  SqlCommand object based on a string sqlStatement, adding to the string does not effect the SqlCommand object.  That was your initial issue.

Comment: Excellent response, again thank you very much for all your help, this is all new to me as I am carrying on from a previous student. You have been a massive help!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just pass the identity? This is much cleaner.

```
UPDATE [TODD].[dbo].[Table] SET Active='1' WHERE RecordID = @RecordId
```

Comment: I prefer your method over my own answer, but the OP did not mention he had a RecordId.

Comment: This was just a suggestion for cleaner code. No questioning you have the correct answer.